# Blazorize project runs but ignores NavMenu.razor

Tags: blazor

I have basic Blazor app -created with the VS Blazor template. It creates a MainLayout.razor and NavMenu.razor by default. After installing Blazorize per the instructions at https://blazorise.com/docs/start/ the app runs but the space where the NavMenu should be is blank.
How do I get it or a replacement to run?